# How do you sheathe your sword? Also, how do I change the default controls?

Tags: the-witcher-2

How do you sheathe your sword in The Witcher 2?  Guards are attacking me in Flotsam and I have no idea how to do it.

Less specifically, is there anywhere I can look at (and ideally change) the default controls?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The launcher contains the video and in game options, it's a bit hidden (screens are from GoG version):

Start the launcher, click on **Video and Language**

[image: Launcher(here, english)]

In the options which are mainly video settings, there is a button below names **Input Settings...**, click that.

[image: Input Settings button]

Double click on current key value for an action, it will turn red, then enter your desired key for that action. Some keys are not bindable to anything else, like I for Inventory or J for journal. That put me off, too, since I use the ZGHJ layout and everything else around it.

You can also find gamepad settings here (Tab Gamepad)

[image: Input settings, key-bindings]

Comment: Wow, what a stupid place to put this. I looked at the gameplay settings, saw that I could only change between keyboard and controller, and assumed that I was stuck with the default keybindings. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Meh, not working with the numpad keys.

Comment: Ok, got the menu as shown (really stupid place for it). But, the buttons can't be changed. No keyboard or mouse button interacting with it. ???

Comment: @micc Have you double-clicked in the input box of the key you wanted to edit?

Answer (score 3):

You can draw and sheathe your steel sword with `1`, and your silver sword with `2`.

For changing the key mappings see Bora's excellent answer.